# TypeScript/JavaScript image rotation and resize

Tags: javascript, image, angular, typescript

I have a requirement where I have to rotate and resize an image using TypeScript (or JavaScript also, since I am using Angular2). This image rotation and resizing feature is similar to MS Outlook (when you compose mail and add images in the body of mail).

I am able to resize and rotate separately but I need it like one combined feature with the below look and feel.

[image]   [image]

```js
var minWidth = 60;
var minHeight = 40;

// Thresholds
var MARGINS = 4;

// End of what's configurable.
var clicked = null;
var onRightEdge, onBottomEdge, onLeftEdge, onTopEdge;

var b, x, y;

var redraw = false;

var pane = document.getElementById('pane');

var e;

// Mouse events
pane.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onUp);

// Touch events 
pane.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchDown);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
document.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd);


function onTouchDown(e) {
  onDown(e.touches[0]);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onTouchMove(e) {
  onMove(e.touches[0]);     
}

function onTouchEnd(e) {
  if (e.touches.length ==0) onUp(e.changedTouches[0]);
}

function onMouseDown(e) {
  onDown(e);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onMove(ee) {
  calc(ee);
  e = ee;
  redraw = true;
}

function onUp(e) {
  calc(e);
  clicked = null;

}

function onDown(e) {
  calc(e);

  var isResizing = onRightEdge || onBottomEdge || onTopEdge || onLeftEdge;
  console.log("isResizing: " + isResizing);

  clicked = {
 x: x,
 y: y,
 cx: e.clientX,
 cy: e.clientY,
 w: b.width,
 h: b.height,
 isResizing: isResizing,
 onTopEdge: onTopEdge,
 onLeftEdge: onLeftEdge,
 onRightEdge: onRightEdge,
 onBottomEdge: onBottomEdge
  };
  
  
}


function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (!redraw) return;

  redraw = false;

  if (clicked && clicked.isResizing) {

 if (clicked.onRightEdge) pane.style.width = Math.max(x, minWidth) + 'px';
 if (clicked.onBottomEdge) pane.style.height = Math.max(y, minHeight) + 'px';

 if (clicked.onLeftEdge) {
   var currentWidth = Math.max(clicked.cx - e.clientX  + clicked.w, minWidth);
   if (currentWidth > minWidth) {
  pane.style.width = currentWidth + 'px';
  pane.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'; 
   }
 }

 if (clicked.onTopEdge) {
   var currentHeight = Math.max(clicked.cy - e.clientY  + clicked.h, minHeight);
   if (currentHeight > minHeight) {
  pane.style.height = currentHeight + 'px';
  pane.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';  
   }
 }


 return;
  }

  // This code executes when mouse moves without clicking

  // style cursor
  if (onRightEdge && onBottomEdge || onLeftEdge && onTopEdge) {
 pane.style.cursor = 'nwse-resize';
  } else if (onRightEdge && onTopEdge || onBottomEdge && onLeftEdge) {
 pane.style.cursor = 'nesw-resize';
  } else if (onRightEdge || onLeftEdge) {
 pane.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
  } else if (onBottomEdge || onTopEdge) {
 pane.style.cursor = 'ns-resize';
  } else {
 pane.style.cursor = 'default';
  }
}

function calc(e) {
  b = pane.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.clientX - b.left;
  y = e.clientY - b.top;

  onTopEdge = y < MARGINS;
  onLeftEdge = x < MARGINS;
  onRightEdge = x >= b.width - MARGINS;
  onBottomEdge = y >= b.height - MARGINS;
  
 
}

animate();


var count = 0;
    $(".btn-rotate").on("click",function(){
        if(count == 0){
            $("#pane").css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
            count++;
        } 
        else if (count == 1){
            $("#pane").css("transform","rotate(180deg)");
            count++;
        }  
        else if (count == 2){
            $("#pane").css("transform","rotate(270deg)");
            count++;
        }
        else {
            $("#pane").css("transform","rotate(360deg)");
            count=0;
        }
    });
```

```css
#pane {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left:200px;
 }
  
  img{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>
You can Resize the Image by Hovering over the edges and drag it
</h1>
 <img src="https://www.bleedingcool.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DC-Logo.png" id="pane" height="100px" width="100px"/>
<button class="btn-rotate">
Rotate Me
</button>
</body>
```

Comment: All jsfiddle links should be accompanied by code. Please provide your code as part of your question.

Comment: Updated the code snippet.. @freginold Do you have  any solution for this question?

Comment: sorry, I don't. Hopefully someone else will though. What you have so far looks really cool. You mean you want to be able to drag the image to rotate it, right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 rotateImage(imgSrc: string, degrees: number): string {
    // cria um elemento imagem
   let image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src=imgSrc;
    // cria um elemento canvas
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // define a largura e altura do canvas para acomodar a imagem após a rotação
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    // pega o contexto do canvas
   const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // move o ponto central do contexto para o centro do canvas
   context!.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  // rotaciona o contexto pelo número de graus especificado
    context!.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    // desenha a imagem no canvas, agora rotacionada
    context!.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
    // retorna o canvas com a imagem rotacionada
    return canvas.toDataURL();
  }
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution, in English, not Portuguese.